# Get result of ManagerAction_QueueStatus in Asterisk

Tags: events, action, asterisk, pbx

How can i get result of **ManagerAction_QueueStatus**.

In event list i can not found corresponding event.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you have permission to see it in manager.conf for your user. Or just allow **all** in read= and check.

Comment: I have permission for see events. My question is that which event show result of this action?

Comment: When you do QueueStatus you will get batch of QueueEntry events with QueueStatusComplete at end. That can be easy spoted in asterisk source code in app_queue.c in manager_queues_status function.

Comment: I use Asterisk 16.5. I listen events Asterisk. When execute action QueuseStatus in Asterisk not generate any events.

Comment: Note: Other action generate corresponding event. Generating other action and listening events is correct.